# Sobre os componentes TADCommand e TADTableAdapter, o que são, para que servem?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, delphi-xe4, firedac

Na suite de componentes adquirida pela Embarcadero para o `Delphi`, o `FireDAC`, existem dois componentes que gostaria de saber sobre eles.
São eles os `TADCommand` e `TADTableAdapter`.

O que são, para que servem esses componentes e poderiam citar um exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `TADCommand` é um componente responsável por executar comandos no banco de dados, ele não pode ser utilizado para prover conteúdo para componentes DBWare pois não é um dataset, seu funcionamento é semelhante a uma TSQLQuery da paleta DBExpress.

O `TADTableAdapter` é o que realiza a comunicação entre o `TADCommand` e a `TADMemTable` que é um DataSet propriamente dito, isto é, faz mais ou menos o mesmo que o `TDataSetProvider` enquanto o `TADMemTable` é muito semelhante ao `TClientDataSet`

Um exemplo de uso é ter um objeto `TADCommand` Vinculado a um `TADTableAdapter` que por sua vez está vinculado a um `TADMemTable`.
Configure uma query no Command e faça o open na memtable.

Para simplificar o uso, este conjunto de componentes, você pode utilizar o TADQuery que tem as funcionalidades dos 3 componentes.